# How to handle Browser Refresh action on Angular 5?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

Currently, I am trying to detect browser refresh event (with F5) and then re-initialize page state once. I simply checked the router events, i.e. if the first event type is NavigationStart and event id is 1, I think a user pressed browser Refresh F5 button.

Sample code shown in below.  However, it looks strange. are there any better way to archive the same goal? or any suggestions? thanks

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

   constructor(private  router: Router) {
     this.router.events.pairwise().subscribe((events: any[]) => {
       if (events[0] instanceof NavigationStart
             && events[0].id === 1 && events[1].id === 1) {

             // re-initialize page sate . . .
    }
  });
```

}

Comment: What is the use case here? When the user refreshes the browser, the app is re-loaded and the page state will be re-initialized automatically.

Comment: `performance.navigation.type === 1` works in most browsers - it means the page was refreshed.

Comment: Hi DeborahK and Bhantol, thank you for your answers and comments. I think I should not handle the  browser refresh specifically. Instead, each angular component should have initialization logic in the ngOnInit method. If browsers are refreshed, all components should be re-initialized as suggested. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I tried below code to check browser reload.

constructor(private router: Router) {

```
   this.subscription = router.events.subscribe((event) => {
    if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
      browserRefresh = !router.navigated;
    }
});
```

}

reference from : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r6-detect-browser-refresh