# How To Run a Function when a page refreshes in Angular10/ Typescript

Tags: angular, refresh, router, angular10

I am working on an Angular 10 app, I would like to navigate to another component using (router.navigate) only when a page refreshes/reloads.
How can i achieve this in Angular.

Thank you
Awaiting responses

Comment: Use redirect in your router.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48391760/how-to-handle-browser-refresh-action-on-angular-5

Answer (score 0):

The refresh of the page should trigger the event handler bound to window:beforeunload.

```
import { Component, HostListener } from '@angular/core'; 
@Component({ ... }) 
export class HomeViewComponent { 
@HostListener("window:beforeunload", ["$event"])
 unloadHandler(event: Event) { 
console.log("Processing beforeunload...");
 // Do more processing...
 event.returnValue = false; 
} 
... 
}
```